# ui slider with text box input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

We have a ui slider we utilise, and it works flawlessly.

code:

```
jQuery(function() {
jQuery( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 1,
    step: 1000,
    min: 0,
    max: 5000000,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        jQuery( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
    }
});
jQuery( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
```

As you can see we allow user to pick anything between 0 and 5,000,000.

Html is:

```
<div id="slider-range-min" style="width: 460px; float:left;margin:10px;"></div>
```

What I want to do is add a text input element which works in harmony with the slider, so as user slides the texy box increases, decreases whatever..

Or if the user types numbers into the input element the slider moves appropriately.

Any help please ?

Preview is:

[image]

Comment: I think you could whip something up using the [range with fixed minimum example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/hotelrooms.html).

Comment: FYI: also found filament group have achieved this, but seemingly they are the only ones.. http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_jquery_ui_slider_from_a_select_element_now_with_aria_support/ would like to see otehrs

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to update the `input` element (like you're doing now for the `#amount` element) on `slide`:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 1,
    step: 1000,
    min: 0,
    max: 5000000,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("input").val("$" + ui.value);
    }
});
```

Additionally, you need to bind to the `change` event for the `input` element and call the slider's `value` method:

```
$("input").change(function () {
    var value = this.value.substring(1);
    console.log(value);
    $("#slider").slider("value", parseInt(value));
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/MD3mX/

There's no validation going on here (you must include the "$" sign for it to work). You could add some more robust input sanitation to enhance it.

Comment: Thats great Andrew, the only issue I see is user cannot type in input element and the slider moves to that priced position, until you click out of the input. I suppose could add onkeyup hey.. But great code, voted up

Comment: @422: That *should* work, you may have to enter a large value to see it (try **$3000000** for example)

Comment: changed div to <div id="slider" style="width: 460px; float:left;margin:40px 10px;"></div> and still doesnt auto update as you type, even with larger numbers. Unless its a jsfiddle issue, will port over to html and test

Comment: need help with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480039/jquery-ui-slider-with-two-handles-with-input-from-two-text-box

Comment: You mean robust like regex? ;-) `/\d+/.exec(this.value)`

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, how to remove dollar sign from input ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed: Remove the dollar sign (`$`) from the code, as well as the substring code http://jsfiddle.net/VfSda/