# JQuery Slider ignores slide/change event

Tags: jquery, jquery-slider

I have a function, which gets called on slider's slide/change events. When my slider gets changed gradually everything works perfectly, however when a slider's handle gets moved sharply the handler function doesn't get executed, but the handle still gets moved. I understand that sync processing kills, bit is there a way to improve that behavior?

Please don't ask for sample, you either know what I'm talking about or don't. Thanks.

Update 1

Just to add some more details - In my slider change function I'm updating canvas, not the lightest call exactly. The only thing I can think of is to use timer and check if the actual handle position matches the last call, which is a big mess.

Comment: Some code could have been awesome,but do see if this question helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523864/ui-slider-with-text-box-input

Answer (score 0):

Well, how about disallowing sharp moves in a graceful manner?
Is it really necessary to have sharp moves?

Comment: Probably by giving a sleep function at the move of each step. I have not tried it, you would have to google.

Comment: is that what you are here for?